# Google Sheet Job update form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google sheet I don't want to share it for everyone. So I need to create a form or something to update that sheet by different members.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1svNfK_9yiwUTjzdzkwJ_lwc_pzyBmT_NQz-UiiKbXm0/edit#gid=0

Google Form https://forms.gle/MYZsARgqSrJK1QaZ8

So in above google sheet in column `A` we have some flat  list and some pending tasks to be updated or tick mark in Column `B, D and F` when there work done.

Example:

1. a member clicks the link and checks Flat 105 and marks Carpenter work done.
2. another member checks same Flat 105 and marks Plumber work done.
   etc. etc..

Actually in google form I can fill entire  row but cant fill individual column and also google form keeps adding new row rather than updating for specific Flat no work done.

Comment: YOu can share and lock certain ranges within the sheet.... using form probably wouldn't be ideal as you can't limit who can access a form aside from hoping the URL isn't shared.

Comment: I don't want to share sheet so I need a option to create a form or something to make it work done.

Comment: That's up to you to figure out

Comment: The shared Google Sheet link on your post does not contain a Google `Form Responses` sheet tab. Does this mean that you have a separate sheet file that contains the form responses? Can you also share at least a screenshot of the form you have created?

Comment: Hi Irvin updated Google form link above. I added all Flat in dropdown list but when changes done it keeps adding in new row.

Answer (score 1):

### SUGGESTION:

Perhaps you can try this implementation:

> **1. Use an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) trigger to run an Apps Script function that will automate the update on your spreadsheet file:**

### Sample Script *UPDATED*:

```
function updateSheetFromForm() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getLastRow();
  var newData =  ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange("A"+lastRow+":C"+lastRow).getValues();
  var dataLast = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastRow();

  for(row=1; row<=dataLast; row++){
    var aData = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A"+row).getValue();
    if(aData == newData[0][1]){
      if(newData[0][2] == "Carpenter Work"){
        ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B"+row+":C"+row).setValues([[true,newData[0][0]]]);
      }
      if(newData[0][2] == "Plumber Work"){
        ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("D"+row+":E"+row).setValues([[true,newData[0][0]]]);
      }
      if(newData[0][2] == "Electric Work"){
        ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("F"+row+":G"+row).setValues([[true,newData[0][0]]]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> **2. Add & save the function `UpdateSheetFromFrom` function to an `onFormSubmit` trigger from the Apps Script Editor as seen below, steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually):**

> [image]

> **3. Then, structure your Google Form & Spreadsheet file tabs like these:**

*NOTE: Make sure the sheets tabs have same exact name `Form Responses 1` & `Sheet1` for the script to run properly*

### Sample Google Form:

- *Based from your sample statement, where you said `"a member clicks the link and checks Flat 105 and marks Carpenter work done."`:*

> [image]

### Sample `Form Responses 1` sheet tab:

> [image]

### Sample `Sheet1` sheet tab:

> [image]

### Sample Demonstration:

- **A member clicks the link (*user accesses the Google Form*) and checks `Flat 105` and marks `Carpenter work` done as seen below. Then,
  clicks `Submit`**

> [image]

- **The `Form Responses 1` sheet tab gets populated:**

> [image]

- **The `Sheet1` automatically updates row for `Flat 105`:**

> [image]

- **When another member checks same `Flat 105` and marks `Plumber work` done:**

> [image]

- **The `Form Responses 1` sheet tab gets populated again:**

> [image]

- **And the `Sheet1` automatically updates row for `Flat 105` again:**

> [image]

Comment: Just in case. Instead of the 12 calls to the server `ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B"+row).setValue(true);
ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C"+row).setValue(newData[0][0]);
ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("D"+row).setValue(false);
ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("E"+row).setValue("");
ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("F"+row).setValue(false);
ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("G"+row).setValue("");` you can use 2 calls: `ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B"+row+":G"+row).setValues([true,newData[0][0],false,"",false,""]);` it's about six times faster

Comment: @YuriKhristich thanks man, I didn't think of that method.

Comment: Ok i will check.

Comment: Irvin - I tried but its updating in form response 1 but not in sheelt1.

Comment: @Demotry Please make sure that the script was pasted & saved on the Apps Script editor [steps here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#google_docs_slides_or_forms) or click **Tools** > **Script Editor** on your spreadsheet file menu. And then the important part, make sure the `updateSheetFromForm` was added & saved as well on the `onFormSubmit` trigger from the Apps Script editor [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqC1O.png)

Comment: If i try to add script from Apps Script it wont show ```Select event Source - From Form``` but it shows From Driven or Calender.

Comment: @sorry I missed that out, you just can choose the event source `From spreadsheet` and then choose `On form submit`

Comment: Hi Irvin. Sorry changed the checkbox to multi choice grid now code is not working. any change to make it work ?